# Find a Context-Free Grammar

Tags: context-free-grammar, context-free-language

I need to find a context-free grammar for the following language:

```
L = { a^m b^m c^k | k <= m }
```

(in order to show that the language is context-free)

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: Are you sure there exists a CFG for this language ?

Comment: Don't think this is cfg